# Laurent Series $\frac{e^z}{z(z-1)}$ when |Z|<1

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm having trouble solving this problem:

Find the Laurent series for $\frac{e^z}{z(z-1)}$ when |Z|<1

I dont think I can just expand $e^z$ and $\frac{1}{(z-1)}$ and multiply the terms as the next question states:

"Write the coefficients cn of the previous series explicitly, for both regions,
when n = 0, ±1, ±2. Hint: when |z| > 1, the coefficients can be expressed as
a familiar infinite series."

How am I meant to do this?
The best I've found so far is forming $e^z$ as $e*(e^{z-1})$ and dividing its taylor series by z and z-1 to get:

$-e∑\frac{(z-1)^{n-1}}{zn!}$ which I dont think is the right answer, as there is still a Z on the bottom and I dont know how to get rid  of it.

Thank-you!

edit: The sum that ive written is from 0 to infinity, I'm searching how to format this correctly just now. Please still help though :)

Comment: You need a series in powers of $z$, not of $z-1$.

Comment: How do we know which series to use? Is it that one with the singularity?

Comment: $|z|<1$ is a disk centred at $0$.  Actually the question should say $0 < |z| < 1$, which is an annulus centred at $0$, because of course the function is not defined at $z=0$.